# My WPF ContextMenu is not dismissing when I click elsewhere

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I have a WPF `ContextMenu` instance declared in my XAML like this

```
<Window.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Do Nothing"/>
        <Separator/>
        <MenuItem Header="{x:Static p:Resources.MenuExit}" Click="IconMenu_Exit"/> 
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.ContextMenu>
```

I'm using the WinForms `NotifyIcon` to display a tray icon like this

```
_notifyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
_notifyIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.mainicon;
_notifyIcon.Visible = true;
_notifyIcon.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(OnTrayIconMouseClick);
```

The implementation of the mouse click handler is this

```
private void OnTrayIconMouseClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

This displays the context menu and clicking on the menu items dismisses it, but if I just click away on another window, the context menu stays visible. This seems like strange default behavior. Is there another way to display the context menu other than `IsOpen` or do I have to explicitly hide the context menu somehow?

Edit: I don't know if it matters but the window's `DataContext` is set to `this` in its code-behind.

Edit2: The context menu dismisses properly if it's invoked by right clicking on the actual main window but not from the tray icon.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have not defined the [StaysOpen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.staysopen(v=vs.110).aspx) property as true.

Comment: I never explicitly set it to true. Even explicitly setting it to false in the XAML I get the same results

Comment: IsHitTestVisible = true ? If the element is a child of an element that is not hittestvisible, the child remains false

Comment: @cjsmith Setting it explicitly to True does not make any difference.